# A biopsy results in dying tissue. What does this mean?

Tags: cancer, lungs, tumors, biopsy, cancer-staging

I'm not a doctor or related in medicine in any way. I'm just a regular Stackoverflow user, and I would like to use my StackExchange experience to acquire knowledge about a bad notification my mother has received this morning:
My mother had gone to the hospital for a biopsy, because during an X-ray examination (in a scanner) a spot was discovered with a size of about 3cm..
This morning my mother was told that the results were inconclusive as the issue sample that has been taken was dying. Nevertheless the term "lung cancer" was expressed.

Since then I've been doing some research on the internet about lung cancer. According to that research, she would be in stage 2 of the illness (because of the size of the tumor). The doctor also said that because of her age (83 years old), surgery is not an option, hence radiation therapy would be done.

I don't understand how to interpret the "dying tissue" subject: is that a good thing (meaning that the tumor is not very strong and is dying) or a bad thing (the tumor is that strong that it manages to kill quite a lot of healthy lung tissue).

Can anybody give me some information? (And is my estimation of the cancer stage correct?)

Comment: Did they use a particular term for the dying? perhaps necrotic? if so this is common in large tumours - the centre gets necrotic as it doesn't have enough blood supply. I'm assuming the biopsy was a fine needle aspirate - which means they poked a needle in there and tried to suck out some cells and bits of tissue. If they hit the centre, then they might have got necrotic cells.

Comment: @bob1 - I think you might be confusing needle aspiration with needle biopsy, which is intended to pull out  plug of tissue which remains in the core of the needle until sent for histological examination.

Comment: @anongoodnurse No, don't think I'm confused here - FNA is commonly used for biopsy of breast lumps.

Comment: @bob1 - FNA is just that: aspiration. FNA is used when lumps have a reasonable probability to be cysts, which is the case in glandular tissue. But for presumed solid masses, a needle biopsy is just that: a biopsy of the tissue to obtain a sample.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I misread the question as breast cancer for some reason, despite the word lung appearing quite a few times. Lung, absolutely core is the way to go.

Comment: @Dominique - We can't even make a guess; it *could* mean the tumor is a rapid growing, disorganized, and highly active metabolically one, hence parts would die, and the tumor would be pretty responsive to radiation. Or it could mean something else. You need to speak with the oncologist handling the case. They are the person with the information about your mother's particular tumor. Sorry to be unhelpful, and I'm sorry to hear about your mother's illness.